# Installing windows 7 from hdd to ssd, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-7, cloning

So I have a x220, it came with a hdd with only windows 7 installed on it. Last week, I backed up the hdd to an external drive, then tried to clone it windows 7 over to the ssd, with my usb y cable to sata cable, with my ssd plugged in, hdd still in computer. I partitioned the ssd for windows, cloned it over successfully, then installed the ssd, but windows wouldn't boot. I didn't feel like missing with windows so I reformatted my ssd to get rid of the partition, took out the hdd. and installed the ssd, put 16.04 on it, and works perfectly. Now, I would like to install windows 7 just in case I am ever going to need it, so that I could dual boot. I have no idea where to start... Can any one help me out? I am going to back up ubuntu now.

Comment: try tidying up the answer, basically all you have asked is how to dual-boot windows and ubuntu

Comment: LOL @warsong it must be contagious because your comment needs tidying up. Your comment says "answer" where it should say "question".

Comment: technically that would be a correction, not a tidy up :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to run Windows in an Virtual Machine like Oracles VirtualBox. Which task would you do with windows?
If you install linux first and windows afterswars, it will rewrite the boottable and you have to repair it. Therefore am VM would be the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yeah, I thought about that. Honestly, I am not really sure.  I know a VM would be easiest, but I only have 8 gigs of ram, and a i5 processor and already run a external monitor, so I'd would be too afraid of getting "bogged" down.

Comment: When Linux is running by itself (no chrome, youtube, libreoffice, etc.) it's only using 1% of available 8 CPU's power on my system. I think then if you ran virtual box the system wouldn't be "bogged down" because Linux isn't doing very much. I also have 8 gb RAM and was tempted to upgrade to 16 but can't justify it because it's always been twice as much as I need. My concern is virtual box doesn't do as much as Windows does, especially for gaming. Another concern would be licensing although that's a pandora's box.